# Creating a new folder or file using Explorer in Windows 7 does not show up in Explorer until Refresh or F5 is pressed

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I am in Explorer on Windows 7 and I create a new folder it does not show up in the right hand pane until I refresh the listing by pressing the **F5** key. I have tried creating a new folder using **right click\new folder** and using the **New folder** option in the menu bar at the top.

Also, once I have refreshed the screen by hitting **F5** and renamed the new folder using **right click\rename**, the old name (New folder) shows up until I hit **F5** again.

This same behavior occurs for files as well. I have other systems running Windows 7 where this is not an issue. Is there a configuration setting to fix this?

Comment: Good answers found in this duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the **ShellIconCache** usually does the trick (Vista and lower). Locate `C:\WINNT\ShellIconCache` (it's a hidden file), delete it and reboot.

In Windows 7, this file seems to have been renamed to **IconCache.db** and is found under `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local`.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Your answer, which applies to older versions of Windows, lead me to the right answer for Windows 7 which was a different file. It was renamed to IconCache.db. It has also been moved to a different location in Windows 7.

Comment: Hmm... it was this file for Vista. Must have just changed in 7. Thanks for the info! I've added it to my answer for completeness if you don't mind.

Comment: +1. Weird quirk, what does `IconCache.db` have to do with this?

Comment: Oddly the only time I can get my folders to be "instantly created" when I click the New Folder button is to delete that file.  I'm actually thinking maybe I'll just write a script to delete it when windows-7 boots.  Is that a safe thing to do?

Comment: I think it's actually the reboot that fixes it not deleting IconCache.db

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Explorer to delete the hidden file **IconCache.db** in `%localappdata%` which is usually `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local` works in Windows 7.

Comment: John's answer lead me to the solution for Windows 7.