# Safe to delete iconcache.db on startup?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

[Creating a new folder or file using Explorer in Windows 7 does not show up in Explorer until Refresh or F5 is pressed](https://superuser.com/questions/71651/creating-a-new-folder-or-file-using-explorer-in-windows-7-does-not-show-up-in-exp)

I was just reading the aforementioned thread, and wondered if it was safe to just delete iconcache.db on startup with a batch file, so that explorer.exe functions without the non-refreshing behavior.

Is there some sort of Windows service that I could just turn off to avoid the re-creation of the file (and the problem) on startup?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have that cache, deleting it just resolves corruption in the cached db file. You should not have to delete it on every boot, only when it becomes corrupted.

Comment: At this point it (despite having WebRoot installed) it appears to become corrupted every time I boot up (because the same behavior always seems to return).  :\

Comment: @leeand00 - it doesn't seem likley to me that this is a virus issue so the fact that your running WebRoot isn't of importance from that prospective.  I'd lean more towards it being related to soemthing installed or a configuration on your computer.  Do you have a sense if this has always been the way your computer has functioned or has it been more recent, perhaps after a system change?

Comment: It's been like that for about a month I would say.  I'll have to see what I've installed lately.