# Explorer does not auto-refresh

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I create a folder or copy files, after the operation finishes I have to manually refresh the Explorer window (<kbd>F5</kbd>). For example, when I create a folder, I don't see the "New Folder" until I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have noticed this behavior, and it *always* goes away after a restart. I have never heard of it persisting after a restart, and I would be interested to hear from anyone who has the problem persist after a restart. For me it kicks in after only a couple of days without a restart. And I have done a fresh wipe and re-install only 3 months ago. Please let me know if restart fixes problem.

Comment: same thing happens after a restart

Comment: Seems like restarting is a working solution (changing Explorer|Search didn't work).

Comment: There's this article that summarizes many of the known possible fixes to the problem. I am not making this a full answer as this will require me to write a synopsis of that article: http://www.itworld.com/article/2827156/windows/what-to-do-when-windows-explorer-doesn-t-refresh.html

Comment: Even killing all the explorer.exe processes and restarting explorer doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is an incredibly simple solution that worked for me.  It may work for you as well:

- In Windows Explorer: choose Tools, Folder Options > Click the Search tab > Check or uncheck ANY option
- Apply.
- If this solves your problem, you can revert to your original setting and the problem will remain solved.

For Windows 10, the folder option is updated to View -> Option in Windows Explorer

Comment: Tools, Folder Options > Click the Search tab > Check or uncheck ANY option - Apply >>>> worked for me...

Comment: Folder Options -> Search tab -> cannot find the "ANY" option :\

Comment: I think you mean "go to Control Panel to choose Tools..." as well as "check and then uncheck any option".

Comment: This worked only until reboot for me. The culprit was a stored not anymore existing FTP-connection

Comment: Wow - this works. ANy way to get it to persist after a restart?

Comment: Astonishing! Seems to really work (on Windows 10), I wonder how long till it stops working again.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the clarification, I believe as well that's what they meant. I just picked a random checkbox and it worked.

Comment: This fixed it. But why!?

Comment: I must admit I was searching for "ANY" option for a bit... Anyway didn't work for me (Windows 7).

Comment: Windows 10 Fall Creator Update v1709. Works like a charm

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 26):

Refer to [Windows 7 does not refresh folder views](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-does-not-refresh-folder-views/9d1ede23-2666-4951-b3b9-b6c1ce3d1ebf) on Microsoft Answers and [Windows Explorer doesn't refresh when moving/deleting](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/8afb8b65-900c-4f42-b1df-3c2394417b6e).  Several posters stated that the issue pertains to the Windows UI Shell and several solutions exist:

- Remove a "Network Connection" that points to a server that is not currently available.
- Disable the Client for Microsoft Networks in properties of Local Area Connection.
- Or simply going through Control Panel -> Folder Options -> View, then click 'Reset Folders'.

Let me know if these links help you out!

Comment: @RemusRigo You're very welcome.

Comment: i'm back at work and it still doesn't refresh :(

Comment: Reset Folders wasn't available for me (was greyed out) until I started when I was on the C: drive, not a subdirectory.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Sorry, updated the answer... a year and two months later.

Comment: Good answer. For me it was the not existing network resource

Comment: Network connections don't point to servers. Do you mean "Network Location" by any chance?  (can't remove those; I need them for local network locations at work)

Comment: All of the solutions so far seem to work for a few minutes, then the behavior reverts back

Comment: None of these solutions worked

Answer (score 4):

A solution that worked for me:
I found that none of the steps advised above (or on other sites) was working.  However, the folder I was working in was part of a "Library."  I found that if I switch to working in the original file location, I no longer have the problem.  It seems that there's a bug with Windows updating views within libraries.

More details:
I was trying to work in Libraries\Dissertation Research, which includes several folders located on various drives.
I switched to working in D:\Dropbox\Academia\Dissertation. Problem solved.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. None of the other solutions above had solved it. My "My Documents" folder is on a non-standard location, on a different disk.

Answer (score 3):

This is my experience: A zombie network-share folder triggered this problem. After I delete that zombie(the X1500 yellow stuff below), auto-refresh works again immediately.

[image]

The proposed "Folder Options > Click the Search tab > Check or uncheck ANY option" workaround is effective for me, but it works only for **current** Explorer window, so closing and reopening one will bring back the bug.

Answer (score 2):

One way to circumvent the issue is to use an alternative file browser, such as [Explorer++](http://explorerplusplus.com/download) (free). The latter is not affected by the auto-refresh issue, and has a few interesting features such as tabs.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use alternatives, I want to fix Windows Explorer

Comment: Another problem using a 3rd part explorer, is the file-browser dialog box, used by application (e.g. Office) will not use the new 3rd part browser.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was a "Libraries" linking problem. I could delete with folder update in my User folders, but no refresh when deleting in the Libraries folders.

Right click on each major folder in Libraries, then Properties, be sure proper type of optimization is selected (Documents, Music, etc.), Restore Defaults, Apply. Delete then updates in the Libraries folders.

I think it rediscovers the folders in their real location on the hard drive and resets that connection with all the proper options restored.

Answer (score 1):

Found something that works for me. Open the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance\
```

and set the value of `DontRefresh` (`REG_DWORD`) key to `0`.

**Note:** If you have a **64 bit** windows (x64), the registry is:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance
```

Also, If you do not see it, you will have to create the path by right-clicking and selecting `New` at each level.

Comment: Just curious, how has this been working out for you?

Comment: hmm.. worked fine for a short time, the next day at work I got the same problem

Comment: i wish that i could reinstall OS, but that is not a serious problem and my colleagues didn't complain...

Comment: That key, `{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}`, does not exist for me. Copied and pasted it into Find, and no results were found.

Comment: search for DontRefresh. That worked once for me. Now I have the problem for third time and I tried all the things I tried before including deleting and recreating this registry value - didn't work this time

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works ***restart*** explorer:

Open `Task Manager` >> `Processes` Tab >> find `Windows Explorer` >> <kbd>right click</kbd> >> `Restart`.

Take note this will lose all opened Explorer windows.

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to solve the issue (In my case), I went to "properties of Local Area Connection" I only had IPV4 checked, so I checked "Client for Microsoft Networks" problem rectified immediately !!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my shared Network Directory Tree refresh issues by adjusting the Windows LAN Manager Server registry parameter IRPStackSize. Increasing the value of that parameter resolved refresh issues on deleted and moved file entries.

1. Open RegEdit
2. HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
3. Find the key "IRPStackSize"

   - Increase the value to 30.
   - Add a new DWORD Value with the value of Decimal 30 if missing
4. Reboot

*Source: [this Microsoft Answer post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/shared-folder-windows-7-does-not-auto-refresh-the/acac6a6c-f77a-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5).*

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and put the essential information here as well. I started doing that but do not understand what you mean with 'sar menu' in your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this party, but making the following registry change fixed my Explorer update problem with no reboot:

Open regedit.exe and create this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Update
```

Then create this dword value:

```
"UpdateMode"=dword:00000000
```

Close regedit and test.
Worked for me on Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me. After two years, I finally solved it:

[Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) was causing the issues.

After uninstall (`choco uninstall linkshellextension`), the problems were gone.

Answer (score -1):

I found that disabling  Client for Microsoft Networks in properties of Local Area Connection worked for me and then I re-enabled it and the problem is still gone...

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it for me:

Open explorer --> right click on Documents --> in the documents library pane click the Restore Defaults button --> click Apply
Problem solved :)

Answer (score -1):

Right click the problem folder to go to folder properties and then click restore defaults.

It's caused by a registry key that can be checked to stop the folder from auto refreshing. This can be checked/unchecked by by processes running but not through the gui.

Answer (score -1):

Client for Microsoft Windows was disabled. I enabled it.

Then I restarted Explorer by executing a bat file with this in it:

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe"
START explorer.exe
```