# Windows explorer fails to auto-refresh after file operations

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I'm having some issues with my Windows Explorer in Windows 8. It fails to auto-refresh upon any file actions. If I create a file or folder, or delete one, I have to navigate away and come back to see the changes. The issue is also affecting my recycle bin. Any ideas?
I've tried refreshing my icon cache and a few registry tweaks but no joy. It was working fine up until a couple of days ago and now it has just stopped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not much, but pressing F5 will refresh the explorer window manually without having to navigate back and forth, just as it does on a Web browser. Also, do you notice this problem in a specific folder more than another? In a library? Personally, I notice that such a thing happens in my Dropbox folder specifically and not elsewhere, which means it's Dropbox's fault. Not that it solves the issue, but whoever has a solution might be thankful. Look: http://i.imgur.com/xHgA4nU.png After renaming "testfile", a "ghost" with the old name, transparent, remains. Does it sound similar to your problem?

Comment: I have seen it many times within Windows 7. There seems to be several possible causes and resolutions,and a bit of discussion in the following locations: - [Part 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8afb8b65-900c-4f42-b1df-3c2394417b6e/windows-explorer-doesnt-refresh-when-movingdeleting) - [Part 2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/09fd46ff-65f1-4fa7-ae2d-9f3b2644fad6/) - [Part 3](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c8b1f896-bbb7-43b8-be8e-5d28916268e0/)

Comment: This isn't a problem with Dropbox. This is an issue with my Documents, Pictures, Videos libraries and my Desktop.

Comment: I have already tried all of these links already from my one Google search. I don't have this problem on my own Windows 8 machine at home but for some reason have this all the time now on my Windows 8 machine at work.

Comment: This issue also affects Windows 7: http://superuser.com/q/390030/116475

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to switch all FolderOptions / View off (and accept these settings) after that you can turn them back to your old values. This worked for me like charm.

1. Open FolderOptions
2. Go to View Tabpage
3. Disable all checkboxes and accept these settings.
4. Go back to your old settings and accept them.