# New files are not sorted automatically by Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, windows-10, file-management

Windows Explorer fails to auto-sort files that are modified in the same window or at the same time in the [Open/Save Dialog box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For instance saving documents in Word does not affect the "Date modified list" and the new file is placed at the bottom of the list.

**In short:**

A new item in the Explorer Window ignores the default sorting and is dropped at the end of the list.

**What does work:**

1. Pressing F5.
2. Reopening the folder.
3. Changing back and forth the sorting order. Same result as F5.

**What doesn't work:**

1. New files are not automatically sorted.
2. Auto-sorting in an Explorer window with changes made by an "Open and Save As Dialog Box".

**Note:** The "Save Dialog Box" auto-sorts properly on it's own.

I tried the solution [listed here](https://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh) for Windows 7 and it did not work for WIndows 10.

Distro: Windows 10 Pro Retail.

Comment: I just checked my Save/Open Dialogs using Microsoft Office and changed the newest date to be at the top of the list which worked fine.  Closed out of Word, for example and did the operation again, the file sort maintained.  if this is not what you are looking for, I think I am still confused.

Comment: The "Open and Save As Dialog Box" does auto-sort properly, however any Explorer window fails to auto-sort recent changes, commonly with the Save Dialog Box. Please review my question and reword it if you find it confusing.

Comment: @IronManMark20 I just tested in another Windows 10 computer and auto-sorting does work properly in Explorer.