# Windows Explorer won't rename folder (e.g. "New Folder" cannot be renamed)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer refuses to rename folders.

Specifically, this occurs when creating a `New Folder` either via `Ctrl-Shift-N` or via `RightClick-New-Folder` and then trying to rename it.
No error messages pop up but the folder remains named `New Folder`.

Also, when hitting `RightClick-New-Folder` again, the `New Folder (2)` does not appear until reloading the folder.

Creating folders with

```
mkdir theFolderNameWeWant
```

works, though.

A reboot did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Explorer: `Organize > Folder and Search Options > View`

enable: `Always Show Icons Never Thumbnails`
 *and* then disable it again.

This answer is similar to a suggested solution from [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-thumbnail-previews-in-windows-vista-explorer/).

This answer seems related to  [explorer-does-not-auto-refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh) question, but I am not allowed to comment/upvote neither do I know if the problem has the same cause.