# afp file server prevents windows 10 FileExplorer refreshing

Tags: windows, mac, windows-explorer, file-management

**The issue**

Have been experiencing a very bizarre issue for the past 3+ months on 3/3 windows 10 computers in our office.

We have a mac mini which is used as a file server. The mac mini works as expected for (new, copy/paste, name change, location change, saving etc.) files for other macs, however the File Explorer on the windows computers are are not refreshing when such a command is issued, to the extent where you have to refresh FileExplorer **EVERY SINGLE TIME** a command is issued (new, copy/paste, name change, fiel directory change, saving, deleting etc. *[you get the idea - infuriating]*)

Not only does it not refresh when FileExplorer is in an afp directory, it also stops working for all FileExplorer's including those inside a local directory. i.e. 2 windows open, 1 in afp directory, 1 in local, both won't refresh on change. My F5 key has taken an absolute bashing - think of the keyboard!!

---

**Attempts at debugging / resolving**

EventViewer returns zero errors, warnings or notifications.

[Resetting dekstop icons to default](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-explorer-doesnt-refresh-by-itself/1d8a73e2-6959-4289-a172-22612c0650cf)

[Unchecking a random option in view settings](https://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh)

When it first started occuring, I assumed it was another windows 10 update gone sour, but evidently this is not the case. Does any please have any insight into how we can resolve this?

---

Sincerely, potentially balding from stress, frustrated programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case I had sone time ago.

The "refresh-not" effekt is a long standing bug which was present even on local disk. When you created a file inside of folder from terminal and it wasn't there until you changed a folder's view. It was "resolved" in Tiger (IIRC) (=marked as resolved by apple) but just for local drives.

It's usual that the polling of afp server volumes isn't "too quick". The main difference against Windows is that the Command-R shortcut doesn't exists on Mac OS X so there is no easy way to refresh window contents. The NewInlineItems notification is just not sent sometimes by the afp server.

We made a case with apple once and got the perfect answer "AFP is no the recommendet protocol infrastructure for this case". We switched to Windows Server (smb) and had no further problems since then. And we got to love the VolumeShadowCopy feature.

Comment: And if switching to smb is not possible?