# Need to refresh Windows folder view using F5

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management

I use Windows 10 with all updates done. When I create a folder, change the name of a file or move files between folders, I have to press the <kbd>F5</kbd> button to make the changes visible.

This anomaly doesn't always happen, but it happens often. Rarely I have the system working correctly (where my changes are updated without the need to press <kbd>F5</kbd>).

How can I solve this problem?

**Information about my system**
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100F CPU @ 3.60GHz 3.60 GHz | 8GB Ram | Windows 10 Pro | Version: 20H2 | OS Build: 19042.1110 | Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0

Comment: Do you occasionally shut your system down? Do you have third-party software that enhances the Windows shell? Do you share folders over a network?

Comment: Do you occasionally shut your system down? Every single day;

Do you have third-party software that enhances the Windows shell? No, and I don't know what kind software it is that;

Do you share folders over a network? No;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explorer does not auto-refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh)

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does the behavior exhibit itself?