# Windows Explorer does not update automatically when new file/folder is created

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, network-shares, mapped-drive

As mentioned in the title, my problem is that every time I create, edit or delete a file/folder in Win Explorer this not update automatically but needs a refresh.
I know the cause are 7 added network locations pointing to devices that most part of the time are offline or powered off. I've tried mapping those locations as network drives, but the problem is the same if not worse.
I need that mapped drives in order to easily access them every time I need, but this problem is annoying me a lot.
Did someone experience the same issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: 1. See https://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh and https://www.thewindowsclub.com/desktop-does-not-refresh-automatically-windows . 2. the F5 key can prompt for a refresh of the view (e.g., if an added item is not correctly sorted, F5 will resort), so try that.

Comment: Are you creating files on a local disk or on a network share?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've tried both the solutions described in those posts, none of them worked.

Comment: @harrymc local disk: desktop, documents folder and so on.