# Root folder on system disk (C:) doesn't get updated under Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have a strange experience under my Windows 7 (HP x64 SP1). Contents of root folder on system disk doesn't get updated (refreshed) automatically, just like for all other folders.

When I have contents of disk C: opened in Windows Explorer, and some external program will create new file or directory in it, I won't see it, until I press F5 to force contents refresh. In any other folder (on any other computer and system version) contents of directory are automatically updated, so I would see that new folder or file created.

If a long file is being saved to my C: folder, for a long period of time (for example: writing DVD disk image) I won't be seeing file size changes, if I won't be pressing F5 repeatedly. Process can take 15-20 minutes and end without any problems, resulting in 4,35 GB file size, but until I refresh C: contents manually, my Windows Explorer will claim that a file has 0 bytes size.

This may seem to be a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/71651/creating-a-new-folder-or-file-using-explorer-in-windows-7-does-not-show-up-in-ex), but it's not. As far as I know, this happens only for root C: folder in my case and I don't have even a traces of `IconCache.db` file (neither in mentioned folder, nor in any other) which deleteion should solve the problem.